# css print striker 3x8 on A4

Tags: html, css

I have to make pages and print them on A4 'striker' paper
(each striker on this A4 papers is used to paste on letter's envelope)
Here is example of this A4 'striker' paper:

[image]

On this A4 paper: there are 3 strikers on the range and 8 strikers on the column.

A4 papier's dimension: W=210mm, H=297mm
striker's dimension: W=70mm, H=35mm
top & bottom margin are 8mm
left & right margin are 0mm (in my case)

**objective:** on print, the strikers must be printed well in the frames

How can I do it?
How I can make independent settings with "page setup" of the browser?

Here are my workaround
It works with navigator's "page setup": margin: left=right=0, top=bottom=8mm

```js
function printthis(){
  if (!confirm("Do you really print it?")) return false;
  $('#etiquetteTableID').removeClass('etiquetteTable').addClass('etiquetteTablePrint');
  window.print();
  setTimeout(function () { $('#etiquetteTableID').removeClass('etiquetteTablePrint').addClass('etiquetteTableAffichage'); }, 1000);
  //window.close();
 }
```

```css
 /* A4: L=210mm, H=297mm, contient 3x8 étiquettes
  Etiquette: L=70mm, H=35mm
  margin: top = 8mm, bottom = 8mm
 */

 /* Display */
 .etiquetteTableAffichage {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width: 210mm;
  border:1px solid black;
  /*position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:8mm;*/
 }

 .etiquetteTableAffichage .etiquetteTD {
  border:1px solid black;
  font-size: 9pt;
  width: 70mm;
  height : 35mm;
  padding-left : 5px;
  padding-right : 1px;
  vertical-align: middle;
 }

 /* Print */
 .etiquetteTablePrint {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width: 210mm;
  border:0px solid black;
  /*position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:8mm;*/
 }

 .etiquetteTablePrint .etiquetteTD {
  border:0px solid black;
  font-size: 9pt;
  width: 70mm;
  height : 35mm;
  padding-left : 5px;
  padding-right : 1px;
  vertical-align: middle;
 }

 html { margin: 0px; border: 0px;} 

 body {
  margin-left : 0px;
  margin-top : 0px;
  margin-right : 0px;
  color : black;
  background-color : #OODDCE;
  background : url("") no-repeat;
 }
```

```html
<center>
 <table id="etiquetteTableID" class='etiquetteTableAffichage'>
 <tr>
  <td class='etiquetteTD'> <!-- 0 -->
   Join Mc 1<br>
   my text 1 <br>
   12345 CITY <br>
   00.00.00.00.00 <br>
   Bâtiment n°: <B>01</B><br>
   N° INUAV: <B>ABCDEF</B><br>
   Lot n°: <B>TTTTTT1022</B>
  </td>

  <td class='etiquetteTD'> <!-- 1 -->
   Join Mc 2<br>
   my text 2 <br>
   12345 CITY <br>
   00.00.00.00.00 <br>
   Bâtiment n°: <B>01</B><br>
   N° INUAV: <B>ABCDEF</B><br>
   Lot n°: <B>TTTTTT1022</B>
  </td>

  <td class='etiquetteTD'> <!-- 2 -->
   Join Mc 3<br>
   my text 3 <br>
   12345 CITY <br>
   00.00.00.00.00 <br>
   Bâtiment n°: <B>01</B><br>
   N° INUAV: <B>ABCDEF</B><br>
   Lot n°: <B>TTTTTT1022</B>
  </td>
 </tr>
 .....
 <tr style='page-break-before: always'> <!-- if the following <td> index % 24 == 0-->
  <td class='etiquetteTD'> <!-- 24 -->
 .....
 </tr>

 </table>
```

Thanks a lot.

--------------- edit1 (with SeeQue's suggestion) BEGIN ----------------------
(with this, i have no more to change class on print but its doestn't resolve my problem!)

```
<style media="print">
/* A4: L=210mm, H=297mm, contient 3x8 étiquettes
    Etiquette: L=70mm, H=35mm
    margin: top = 8mm, bottom = 8mm
*/
html { margin: 0px; border: 0px;} 

body {
    margin: 0px;
    color : black;
    background-color : #OODDCE;
    background : url("") no-repeat;
}

/* Print */
.etiquetteTableAffichage {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width: 210mm;
    border:0px solid black;
    /*position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:8mm;*/
}

.etiquetteTableAffichage .etiquetteTD {
    border:0px solid black;
    font : 9pt;
    width: 70mm;
    height : 35mm;
    padding-left : 5px;
    padding-right : 1px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>

<style media="screen">
html { margin: 0px; border: 0px;} 

body {
    margin: 0px;
    color : black;
    background-color : #OODDCE;
    background : url("") no-repeat;
}

/* Affichage */
.etiquetteTableAffichage {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width: 210mm;
    border:1px solid black;
    /*position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:8mm;*/
}

.etiquetteTableAffichage .etiquetteTD {
    border:1px solid black;
    font : 9pt;
    width: 70mm;
    height : 35mm;
    padding-left : 25px;
    padding-right : 1px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
```

--------------- edit1 (with SeeQue's suggestion) END ----------------------

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but as i see it you should use the "media" attribute on your style tag instead of removing classes when printing. for example:

```html
<style media="print">
  h1 {color:#000000;}
  p {color:#000000;}
  body {background-color:#FFFFFF;}
</style>
```

You can find a list of possible medias here:
[w3schools docs](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_media.asp)

But the ones you are interested in are "screen" and "print", and you should simply make two different style sections with the same classes, and the one with "print" as media should automatically be used when printing.

Other than than then HTML is not the most precise format for printing, and is still depending on the printer margins (which is different for almost each printer model)